# Upload File - Customizing Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, upload

How can I do to browse my files when i click in a button "Upload" ?

I need to create a hidden file input?

More Explain:

I can't edit css of input type file of my html forms. So in each browser I have a different layout. I don't want it. I want to customize my form.

I created a button. When I click on the button, I want to appear the file selection screen.
When I select the file and press ok , I want to put the path string of my file in the input that I created.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you provide more information? You need to use the `file` html form element.

The `file` element lets you browse your local documents naturally.

To process the file attachment you need to know a programming language like `php`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <label for="showpath">File Upload:</label>
    <input id="showpath" type="text" onclick ="javascript:document.getElementById('CommentFile').click();"/>
    <button type="button" onclick ="javascript:document.getElementById('CommentFile').click();"></button>
    <input type="file" name="data[Comment][file]" id="CommentFile" style='visibility: hidden;' onchange="updateInput(this.value,'showpath')"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<input type='file' />`

More info at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).